# Generated ZIP file is corrupt / invalid

Tags: java, zipoutputstream

I'm trying to create a simple ZIP file in Java, but once generated, I can't open it with either Windows Explorer or 7-zip, as they say the file is invalid / unrecognized / corrupted.

However, I'm following all the tutorials I've seen and using a very simple code, so I don't see where I went wrong. Here's the simplest snippet I could think of to reproduce the problem:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.zip");
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry("test.txt");
zos.putNextEntry(ze);
byte[] data = "content".getBytes();
fos.write(data, 0, data.length);
zos.closeEntry();
zos.finish();
zos.close();
```

Did I miss a setting somewhere?
For reference, I've uploaded the `test.zip` file [here](https://hostr.co/yt6NAJBxOpol).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're writing to the wrong stream.

```
  // fos.write(data, 0, data.length);
  zos.write(data, 0, data.length);
```

Comment: Well here's an hour well wasted! Thanks for the quick reply (I'll accept when S/O lets me).